# Cant assign php variable to script

Tags: javascript, php, clipboard

So i am using this script to copy text to the clipboard that needs to be compatible with firefox and chrome at a minimum.

https://github.com/lgarron/clipboard.js

Basically i have some html stored in a php variable and im trying to copy that to the clipboard.The other way i could do it is to copy the contents of a div to the clipboard but basically same result

```
<script src="js/clipboard.js"></script>

<script>
    document.getElementById('markup-copy').addEventListener('click', function() {
        var val = '<?php echo $myText ?>';
        clipboard.copy({
            'text/plain': 'Paste this into a HTML editor.',
            'text/html': val;
        }).then(
        function(){console.log('success'); },
        function(err){console.log('failure', err);
        });

    });
</script>";
```

Ive also tried doing the same but echoing the string directly i.e

```
'text/html': '<?php echo $myText ?>';
```

The script does print out the actual string of html however when i copy it to the clipboard all i see is:

```
<?php echo $myText ?>
```

So even though the page translates the above to the string, this script doesnt seem to. Any ideas?

The $myText variable is a string with  and some basic HTML, no php.

I want to avoid using a flash based solution however if this simply wont work then ill settle to do it in flash.

Comment: there is a syntax error, no need of `;` after `val`

Comment: In other words, when the click happens you want the PHP variable to be echo'ed to that variable?

Comment: is it inside a php echo statement? `</script>";`

Comment: If the PHP tags aren't processed, this means that either the script is not run through PHP at all, or this piece of JS code is actually embedded inside a PHP string. The error is in that area, outside of the actual code you posted.

Comment: Are you sure `$myText` does not contain any single quotes? If it does then it will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**replace**

var val = `'<?php echo $myText ?>';`

to

var val = `<?php echo $myText; ?>`

Answer (score -1):

Replace

```
var val = '<?php echo $myText ?>';
```

with

```
<?php echo 'var val = "'.$myText.'";'; ?>
```

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen:  you can use this for readable format <?php echo "var val = '$myText'"; ?>